# Can Kubernetes ever create a Docker image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes and I'm learning about it.
Are there any circumstances where Kubernetes is used to create a Docker image instead of pulling it from a repository ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options exist to create docker images inside Kubernetes.

If you are already familiar with docker and want a mature project you could use docker CE running inside Kubernetes. Check here: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker and look for the dind tag (docker-in-docker). Keep in mind there's pros and cons to this approach, so take care to understand them.

Kaniko seems to have potential but there's no version 1 release yet.

I've been using docker dind (docker-in-docker) to build docker images that run in production Kubernetes cluster with good results.

Answer (score 5):

Kubernetes natively does not create images. But you can run a piece of software such [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) in the kubernetes cluster to achieve it. Kaniko is a tool to build container images from a Dockerfile, inside a container or Kubernetes cluster.

The kaniko executor image is responsible for building an image from a Dockerfile and pushing it to a registry. Within the executor image, we extract the filesystem of the base image (the FROM image in the Dockerfile). We then execute the commands in the Dockerfile, snapshotting the filesystem in userspace after each one. After each command, we append a layer of changed files to the base image (if there are any) and update image metadata